# Audio and microphone configuration of usb sound card on r-pi

Tags: raspbian, audio

To configure audio of soundcard I did the following settings:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

I commented options `snd-usb-audio index=-2`

and added options `snd_bcm2835 index=1`

so speaker was properly working with usb sound card

now for microphone configuration I went to

```
sudo nano /etc/asound.conf
```

and did the following changes:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

using arecord only noise is recorded and also i am not able to play files through speakers.

I am using Storite 7.1 Channel USB External Sound Card Audio Adapter With Mic and r-pi B+ model

Comment: Have you looked at this http://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/using-a-usb-audio-device-with-a-raspberry-pi--mac-55876?

Comment: yup i have looked upon this site. but changing in sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf only configures audio part of usb not microfone and i need both

Answer (score 1):

The trick is is in `~/.asoundrc`

If you have already gone into `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and changed `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` to `options snd-usb-audio index=0` then:

**First:**

`sudo nano ~/.asoundrc`

**Second:**

Add

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

Then save and reboot your Pi.

This works because when you add `options snd-usb-audio index=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` it only sets your usb card at index 0, it doesn't enable it.

Cheers!